# Welcome, Woodworkers

Tags: discussion

It took a year and a half, but we finally have a Stack Exchange site to get help and exchange advice on our woodworking projects.

However, the work isn't done yet and we'll need a lot of activity to make it past private beta. Here are some things we should focus on now.

### Contribute quality questions and answers

Advice on how to ask good questions is all over the beta phase of this site. Read the advice and make sure you are taking the time to follow it. It's much better for the community to ask and answer questions properly than to be the first one.

### Moderate poor questions

There is a far greater level of woodworking expertise outside of the Stack Exchange network than within it. We would like to attract as much of it as we can, but the people who bring it will all make mistakes. They will come expecting the exchange of knowledge to be like the forums they have seen. When moderating, we should make sure to be patient and not make any assumptions about how well the other person understands how Stack Exchange works. It's a good idea to over-explain things and provide links the site's help center when appropriate.

### Spread the word

Although the beta says "private", there's nothing private about it. Anyone can join and participate. The sooner we spread the word, the more effect it will have.

---

What am I missing? Contribute your own advice, especially if you have experience launching SE sites.

Comment: Excellent point about explaining the "Stack Exchange Method" to new users.

Comment: I think the whole idea of being polite, respectful and understanding of new users and their lack of prior experience on stack sites would be very important to keep in mind.  Just think "is my response something I'd say to my grandparent?"  If not, might want to revise that snarky comment!